# Mouse interaction with nested movieclips in Away3D

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I am building a globe with the countries. I have all of the spheres built and everything works fine. The problem is to get the globe to look right I had to put all of the movieclips into one big moveclip then broke down from there. The problem is I cannot get Away3D to recognize the secondary movieclips. If I apply the listener to the whole sphere it works fine (but that isn't functional). Is there a way to use nested movieclips in away3d?

```
//what works
var materialMovie:MovieClip = new causticsMovie() as MovieClip;
var causticsMaterial:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial( materialMovie);
var sphere:Sphere = new Sphere({material:causticsMaterial, radius:300,segmentsH:18,segmentsW:26, interactive:true});
causticsMaterial.interactive = true;
view.scene.addChild(sphere);

sphere.addEventListener(MouseEvent3D.MOUSE_DOWN, NA);

//what doesn't

world_map.northAfrica_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent3D.MOUSE_DOWN, NA);
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand how 3d engines in flash generally work, this won't be possible. They create a texture from the original movieclip(s) which they then transform. So there are no movieclips left to click on.

There is a couple of ways around this I think. You could transform the click location into polar coordinates (I'm not sure about the maths there, but google should be helpful), and figure out which location was clicked that way.

Or, you could (probably) have a second, invisible sphere (off stage or not added as a child, not sure which will work), where you create a different texture where each country has a different color. You would rotate this to the same angles as the visible sphere. Then, on click, render that to a BitmapData and check the pixel value of the point you clicked (translated so the point on the visible sphere and the invisible sphere are the same). I think this way is the easier of the two, and will have better results.

Comment: Ya that is pretty much what I figured out. I was just hoping I was wrong. The second solution is the more viable of the 2 considering the planet rotates (to show day to night) as well as rotates around the sun. I already had the world map sphere created so the second solution is the best solution. Thank you for the input.